# Iptables HTTP not working on computer

Tags: networking, server, iptables, policy

By default I have an implicit deny so I used these two commands to try to enable http on ip address 10.1.10.201 but I cannot access any websites.

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.1.10.201 --dport http -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 10.1.10.201 --dport http -j ACCEPT

Chain INPUT (policy DROP)      
target  prot  opt  source       destination
Accept  all   --   10.1.10.201  0.0.0.0/0    tcp  dpt:80

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)      
target  prot  opt  source       destination
Accept  all   --   10.1.10.201  0.0.0.0/0    tcp  dpt:80

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)   
target   prot opt source  destination
```

When I access websites it says the server is not found. I am using a windows xp vm to try to access the ubuntu server that is a router/firewall

Comment: Please post the full iptables output too, so we can help you better. E.g. `sudo iptables -L -n -v` (and with `-t nat` if you use NAT)

Comment: That is literally the only two things on my ip table aside from Chain Input (policy Drop) , Chain Forward (policy Drop), Chain Output (policy Accept).

Comment: Please just post the full output in your question body to see the result of your stated commands. Comments aren't for that. This is a Q&A site, not a forum, so please always [edit] your question to include details.

Comment: Aslo: are you aware you won't be able to access web sites with just these two rules? There's more than just port 80 traffic to get to a web site. E.g.: DNS, TCP established accept, etc.. So please also include in your question body what the error is when you try to access web sites. Please make sure you copy&paste the exact error code from your browser/curl etc. Also include more details on what you are trying to achieve. Are you buidling a router/gateway? And from what machine are you trying to access the websites?

Comment: Just posted the output

Comment: You didn't post your nat table, as asked for above. Please post it.

Answer (score 1):

So why dont you use ufw ?

Its so simple to implement firewall on ubuntu, to open port 80 on all your network card you only need
- sudo ufw allow 80
- sudo ufw enable

to make sure if your web server is running use *netstat -nat*
it will display all service in all port

Answer (score 0):

The question is not completely clear to me. From what machine with what IP number in what network do you try to reach out to what other machine? Also, you do not explicitly tell if your setup ever worked before you set up your website.

Guessing: If your iptables are complete the way that you put them, then this indeed explain the symptoms you describe. You just allow input from that particular IP number and not from any other. What you are likely to achieve is to allow contacts to your site from remote sites that you have contacted from your machine before, so they can deliver the data you requested. You achieve that with

```
iptables -m comment --comment "Allow related packages from the InterNet" -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

To constrain the access to your website to the internal network, you may also want to specify the network device that your web server listens on. The "netstat" tool or "lsof -i" is educational on what service may be contacted from where.